# Проблема с сохранением данных из одной таблицы TADOTable в другую - Delphi

Tags: ado, delphi

Здравствуйте. 
Я начал делать программу-регистрационный лист для соревнований, где сохраняются команды. 
Программа устроена следующим образом: есть база данных, в ней есть таблица "Общая таблица участников", есть таблица "Пары", есть таблица "Таблица пар". 
Когда участник приходит, то он заполняет регистрационный лист программы. Там он указывает имя, фамилию, отчество, телефон, и название команды. После нажатия кнопки сохранения регистрации сначала в таблицу "Общая таблица участников" заносятся имя, фамилия, и т.п.. Если команды не существует, то в таблице "Таблица пар" создается строка с его (регистрирующегося участника) ключём (ключ определяется с помощью комбинации функций SelectPerson и GetUsual - код приложен ниже). ключ сохраняется в первое поле "таблицы пар". В "Парах" создается строка с полем "общий номер пары" и полем "место в соревнованиях". Общий номер пары определяется по ключу в "таблице пар". Место в соревнованиях определяется после соревнований. Если участник пришел после первого, то просто в таблице пар сохраняется его ключ в другом поле. 
Но когда я написал код к программе, я обнаружил, что когда сохраняется команда в "Парах", то создается лишь пустая строка, а значение "общий номер пары" остается пустым. Подскажите - в чём проблема? 
Заранее благодарен.
Код SelectPerson:

```
function TFRegistrationForm.SelectPerson(phone:string):boolean;
var NoErrors:boolean;
begin
NoErrors:=true;
try

NoErrors:=DBComponents.TAll.Locate('Телефон',
                     phone,
                     []);
except
NoErrors:=false;
end;
Result:=NoErrors;
end;
```

Код GetUsual:

```
function TFRegistrationForm.GetUsual:integer;
begin
Result:=DBComponents.TAll.FieldByName('Код').Value;
end;
```

Код функции, с помощью которой я выделяю нужную строку пар:

```
    function TFRegistrationForm.SelectPair(PairName:string):boolean;
    begin
    Result:=DBComponents.TPairTable.Locate('Название пары',
                               PairName,
                               []);
    end;
```

Код функции отправки в базу данных "пар":

```
procedure TFregistrationForm.PostPairTable;
begin
DBComponents.TPairTable.Edit;
DBComponents.TPairTable.Post;
end;
```

Код функции отправки в базу данных "таблицы пар":

```
procedure TFregistrationForm.PostPair;
begin
DBComponents.TPair.Edit;
DBComponents.TPair.Post;
end;
```

Код функции, с помощью которой я пытаюсь сохранить изменения:

```
function TFRegistrationForm.RegisterPair:boolean;

var NoError:boolean;
IsPair:boolean;

begin
NoError:=true;
with DBComponents.TPairTable do
    begin

      try
          SelectPerson(EPhone.Text);
          IsPair:=SelectPair(EPairName.Text);
          if not IsPair then append;

          Edit;
          if not IsPair then
            begin
              FieldByName('Общий номер 1-ого участника(цы)').Value:=GetUsual;
              FieldByName('Название пары').Value:=EPairName.Text;

              DBComponents.TPair.append;
              DBComponents.TPair.Edit;
              DBComponents.TPair.FieldByName('Номер                           пары').Value:=FieldByName('Код').Value;
          PostPair;
        end
        else FieldByName('Общий номер 2-ого участника(цы)').Value:=GetUsual;

        PostPairTable;
        PostPair;
  except
    NoError:=false;
  end;
end;

Result:=NoError;
end;
```

Возможно я пропустил какие-то функции. Если да, то я отредактирую тему. 
Подскажите - почему не сохраняется номер пары?

Answer (score 1):

ошибка в том, что вы делаете append а потом сразу edit, уберите edit - он лишний, если вы вставляете строки. edit нужен только если редактируете текущую запись. В частности:

```
if not IsPair then 
  append
else
  edit;
```

и в остальных случаях тоже - либо edit либо append...